# how to launch other program in WPF like windows form process.start

Tags: wpf

i used process.start in windows form to launch other program but now i want to use wpf to launch it and i dont know how and what is equivalent to it ?

```
<Button Margin="0,362,-432,-88" Name="activation" Click="button1_Click"
        Foreground="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="134" Grid.Column="1">
    activate virtual mouse
</Button>
```

Answer (score 13):

You can still use `Process.Start` from the C# code behind with WPF.

In your button click handler have:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Process virtualMouse = new Process();

    virtualMouse.StartInfo.FileName = "VirtualMouse.exe"; // Needs to be full path
    virtualMouse.StartInfo.Arguments = ""; // If you have any arguments

    bool result = virtualMouse.Start();
}
```

The `Process` class in the `System.Diagnostics` namespace [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx). You need to have a reference to that in your code and project.

Add:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

to the .cs file. There's no need to add a reference as this namespace is in "system.dll" which you will have in your project.