# How to create WPF window containing multiple WPF Windows/Classes?

Tags: wpf, xaml, templates, inheritance

From what I can read from similar questions WPF should be based on the class, which is fine.

I'm writing myself an asset management tool to keep track of my stock, licenses  and networked devices. I am for networked devices, I am creating a class I'll call ComputerAsset which will be made up of 3 classes Asset, NetworkConnectionDetails and ComputerDetails.

For the sake of simplicity I'll only pick a few variables from each class.
Asset will contain a unique asset ID, the device serial number.
NetworkConnectionDetails will contain a list of IP and MAC addresses and if they are Wifi, Ethernet or bluetooth
ComputerDetails will contain the processor, size of RAM and hard drives and operating system details.

What I want to do is create a template for each of the three, so...
Asset() would be a WPF Window with just labels and text boxes.
NetworkConnectionDetails would be a WPF Window with a DataGridView
ComputerDetails would be a WPF window similar to Asset

What I want to do is create a WPF window for ComputerAsset and use the WPF for each class in a layout I create for the WPF window. The obvious reason being if I decide to expand any of the assets, it automatically updates the available info across any WPF windows which use the Asset class?

I'm having trouble finding info on this (or could possibly be using the wrong search terms!)

Is it possible to use a WPF window to contain other WPF windows?

Here is a link to a visual example of what I am trying to do which may explain it better. I want to be able to have set WPF windows I've created and insert them into another WPF window, not open new ones. Essentially build a single WPF windows composed of other WPF windows/classes.

Image: https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipM1iVC79w-ZSIqYeOBioU9DyFdeFUYKS43riqi80N8kqxJ5wajekWg72GQxdFQuRQ/photo/AF1QipOtva3EliD8BIzbNb_aPGE5ks1GjoitqZNJlLMC?key=c3ZvdXVFU1lyTDJjTmNWMzA5dldUNTNERHVRYUtn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope your requirement is to have a main window and open windows from it as its child. To achieve that, just set the owner of the new window to main window and it should work fine for your requirement.

Here is a code sample :

Add a new Window to your project by clicking `Add -> Window`. You're already having `MainWindow` by default. The new window is `MainWindow2.xaml`.

At any point in your application when you want to create a new window, just do this in your `MainWindow` :

```
MainWindow2 mainWin2 = new MainWindow2();
mainWin2.Owner = this;
mainWin2.Show();
```

This way, when the application is closed, the sub windows are also closed.
If you're planning to start a new WPF application from your current WPF application, then give [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065091/how-to-launch-other-program-in-wpf-like-windows-form-process-start) a read.

Comment: Sorry I think you've misunderstood what I was wanting to do... I wanted to have 3 classes (each with a WPF window) but insert each onto a single WPF window. Here's a visual example... I want to be able to re-use the classes in multiple Types of asset. PICTURE: https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipM1iVC79w-ZSIqYeOBioU9DyFdeFUYKS43riqi80N8kqxJ5wajekWg72GQxdFQuRQ/photo/AF1QipOtva3EliD8BIzbNb_aPGE5ks1GjoitqZNJlLMC?key=c3ZvdXVFU1lyTDJjTmNWMzA5dldUNTNERHVRYUtn

Comment: @FridgeMagnet : Why do you need 3 windows? This can be achieved with one window itself. Just try to create window like view inside the grid using grid/panel.

Comment: It's essentially me wanting to create a class with a particular layout and then create a window incoprorating those layouts. If this wasn't WPF... and was classes alone, the ComputerAsset class would be composed of the 3 classes (asset, networkconnectiondetails(ncd) and ComputerDetails), the TouchscreenAsset(TSA)  class (asset, ncd, touchscreendetails). What I am looking to do for each (asset, ncd) is have a standard set of labels or textboxes with each when I build the ComputerAsset or TouchscreenAsset, it builds the pre defined layout I have for asset or ncd into the Window.

Answer (score 0):

You could find a way to have the three windows navigate between each other with buttons, and please share your results because I am facing a similar challenge

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34859952)